# Compute the length of each string in a set

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, string-manipulation, counting

Say I have done some computation, and it gives me the following set of string:

```
strings = {"0", "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", 
 "00", "0", "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", 
 "101001000010010000100001001000010010", "00", "0", "10", "00", "0", 
 "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", 
 "101001000010010000100001001000010010", "00", "0", "10", "00", "0", 
 "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", "10", "00", 
 "0", "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", "10", 
 "00", "0", "10", "0", "101001000010010000100001001000010010", "00", 
 "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", 
 "101001000010010000100001001000010010", "00", "0", "10", "00", "0", 
 "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", "10", "00", 
 "0", "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", "10", 
 "00", "0", "10", "0", "101001000010010000100001001000010010", "00", 
 "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "0", "10", "00", "0", "10", "00"};
```

Is there anyway for me to create a list (or table or anything) that shows the $ (\text{length} - 1) $ for each string above?

I cannot even achieve the first step: shows the length for each string. I tried `StringLength` and `Length`, neither worked.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `yourstrlen[s_]:=StringLength[s]-1; Map[yourstrlen,{...yourlistofstrings...}]` If that doesn't work then scrape-n-paste your sample input and this code and the output from it edit that into your post above and maybe someone can help figure out why it isn't working for you.

Comment: `StringLength /@ yourListOfStrings - 1`

Comment: `StringLength @ yourListOfStrings - 1` . @LouisB since `StringLength` is Listable, @ is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringLength[strings] - 1
```

gives

> ```
> {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 35, 1, 0, 
>  1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 35, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
>  1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 35, 1, 0, 1, 
>  1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 35, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
>  0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 35, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
>  0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}
> ```

Is this what you want? Or have I misinterpreted your question?

Comment: Yes this is what I want. So I just use this commend right after I got the string? Or I should copy the string in my post to the [strings]?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical. I copied the code in your question and evaluated it before I evaluated the code you see above. You can use the form `StringLength[...] - 1` anywhere. You might have enclose it in parentheses in some cases.

Comment: Great. Thank you!